# Does Forcing GPU Rendering Affect Battery Life?

Tags: oneplus-3, gpu

I'm currently unsure about this and haven't found anything concrete while searching on the internet. I just recently got my first Android phone a week ago and started tinkering with the developer settings, I am currently using a OnePlus 3T with Android Nougat. Any answers will be appreciated.

TLDR: Does enabling force GPU Rendering affect battery life on the OnePlus 3T with Android Nougat?

Answer (score 2):

Almost all updated apps have GPU Rendering coded into the build. The reason you have an option under developer settings is simply to test the feature as a developer.

Unless you are ok with the minimal performance increase at the cost of battery life keep it off, if an app can utilize the function it will.